# Heap memory blows up when using long-running promises together with stream Nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, stream, heap-memory

I have an express server that

1. Upon a request, read an local jsonl file (Have to be streams, memory is 1st goal)
2. At each line, do some transformations
3. After each 500th line, gather them and call some API to put them into database
   To achieve this, I use readLine for step 2 and promise for step 3
   But it seemed that the memory blows up which defeat the goal of using streaming in the first place

```
//The readline lib
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: stm, //The read stream
    crlfDelay: Infinity
});
      rl.on('line', function(line) {
        var tmpJsonObject=JSON.parse(line) //And may be do some transformations
        bulkArrayForImport.push(tmpJsonObject)// Store until 500 in outer scope variable

        if(bulkArrayForImport.length>500){
          var tmpArray=databaseDriver.import(bulkArrayForImport).then((info)=>{
            //This is the promise provided from database driver
          }).catch(e=>{
            //Promise error
          });

          bulkArrayForImport=[]; //Reset it .Do it here does next to nothing if the promise is long
        }

})
```

To my understanding, this is because `bulkArrayForImport` reference for each particular promise is retained and cannot be GC if the promises are not resolved or reject yet.

Can someone verify if my understanding is correct or not and how can I reduce the memory usage?

Comment: Some thoughts ...
1. What is the `tmpArray = ...` assignment designed to achieve? 
2. How do you handle the terminal (or only) batch if it is less than 500 lines in length?
3. Is it important that whatever goes on in the `.then(info => {...}` clause is carried out in the same order as the line batches? If so then you will need do something to enforce that order. As it stands, the `databaseDriver.import()` processes may complete in some arbitraty order.

Answer (score 1):

You can await the steam line by line like below from the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_symbol_asynciterator)

```js
let bulkArrayForImport = [];

async function processLineByLine() {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: stm, //The read stream
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    // Each line in the readline input will be successively available here as
    var tmpJsonObject = JSON.parse(line);
    bulkArrayForImport.push(tmpJsonObject);
    if (bulkArrayForImport.length > 500) {
      try {
        const info = await databaseDriver.import(bulkArrayForImport);
        bulkArrayForImport = []; //Reset it
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

processLineByLine();
```